# restate a subquery using a join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

The requirement is to find all books that have the same subject code as the book with the title 'The art of Walt Disney', using a table join instead of a subquery, like the below one that I wrote.
The issue I am facing is that I am not quite sure on how to filter the results based on the required criteria without using a subquery to do so. Here is what I have so far

```
SELECT ISBN, Title, Subject_Code
FROM Book
where Subject_Code = Book.subject_Code
ORDER BY Title;
```

This is my create statement to clarify what sort of tables I am working with. Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subject
    (SubjectCode nvarchar(3) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    Subject nvarchar(15)); 




CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Book 
    (ISBN nvarchar(13) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Title nvarchar(50), Author nvarchar(30),
    Publisher nvarchar(30), 
    Subject_Code nvarchar(3),
    Shelf_Location nvarchar(7), Fiction bit(1), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Subject_Code) REFERENCES subject(SubjectCode));
```

Comment: You'll land with an auto-join, which is perfectly legal. Though this tends to imply that your DB is not normalized (looks like values are not atomic in Book table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL you can join a table with itself. Consider something like the following:

```
SELECT b2.ISBN, b2.Title, b2.Subject_Code
FROM Book b1
LEFT JOIN Book b2 ON b1.Subject_Code = b2.Subject_Code
WHERE b1.Title = "The Art of Walt Disney"
```

Comment: I sort-of understand the answer, but not the upvote.

Comment: Not me but I imagine its because he beat you by 11 seconds

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a self-join:

```
select b.*
from book b join
     book bwd
     on b.subject_code = bwd.subject_code
where bdw.title = 'The Art of Walt Disney'
order by title;
```

The condition can go either in the `on` clause or the `where` clause.